# Is a broker required to create a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I list the brokers using: `/opt/confluent-kafka/v5.5.0/bin/zookeeper-shell localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids`

Which returns:

```
Connecting to localhost:2181

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[0]

Which shows no brokers running.
```

I then create a topic using:

```
[test@bhop logs]$ /opt/confluent-kafka/v5.5.0/bin/kafka-topics --create \
>     --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
>     --replication-factor 1 \
>     --partitions 1 \
>     --topic test
Created topic test.
```

And can see the topic is created:

```
/opt/confluent-kafka/v5.5.0/bin/kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

returns:

```
__confluent.support.metrics
test-topic
```

As there are no brokers running how can a topic be created? Is a running broker not required to create a topic ?

Comment: I guess it depends how you define the "creation" of a topic. If you say a topic is created just by having some meta information stored somewhere (e.g. Zookeeper) or if you want actual data stored in the topic for which a broker is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[0]` shows there's one broker with id 0. The ids znode would not exist if no brokers were running

You should `get /brokers/ids/0` to see the broker data

If it looks correct, things are working as expected

Note: `--zookeeper` flag is deprecated in latest Kafka CLIs